# Condense my JavaScript into lesser code

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, nodelist

I have some JavaScript code and it's working (kind of). I'd like to condense it somehow, maybe grab both the CSS selectors at once and iterate through them with a `forEach()` loop of some kind.

Right now, the `top` value for both stars gets the same value, eg `style="top: 60%"`. I'd like to have them get *different* random values for the `top`, `left`, `right` and `transform`.

I realize the `querySelectorAll` will return a NodeList, and can be converted to an array, but I cannot figure out how to do this and have it so the `.shooting-star-right` gets different values using the `Math.random` section.

I've tried this:

```
var stars = document.querySelectorAll('.shooting-star, .shooting-star-right');

for (let el of stars) {
    shootingStar();
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
var stars = document.querySelectorAll('.shooting-star, .shooting-star-right');

stars.forEach(function() {
    shootingStar();
});
```

Here is my working (although quite messy) code => any help is much appreciated :)

```
init: () => {
        let star = document.querySelector('.shooting-star');
        let starRight = document.querySelector('.shooting-star-right');

        const shootingStar = () => {
            setInterval(() => {

                let topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1,
                    topPosRight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1,
                    leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1,
                    rightPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1),
                    trans = Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) + 1,
                    transRight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 220) + 1;

                topPos = topPos + '%',
                topPosRight = topPosRight + '%',
                leftPos = leftPos + '%',
                rightPos = rightPos + '%',
                trans = trans + 'deg',
                transRight = transRight + 'deg';

                star.style.top = topPos,
                star.style.left = leftPos,
                star.style.transform = 'rotate(' + '-' + trans + ')';

                starRight.style.top = topPosRight,
                starRight.style.right = rightPos,
                starRight.style.transform = 'rotate(' + transRight + ')';

            }, 9000);
        };
        shootingStar();
    }
```

Comment: You might like this site for questions like this as well: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `el` has to be used in the `forEach` or `for` `of` loop. For example (not tested):

```js
function setStyles(name, style) { 
  for (let el of document.getElementsByClassName(name)) el.style = style; 
  // or document.getElementsByClassName(name).forEach(el => el.style = style); 
}
const r = n => Math.random() * n | 0 + 1;

setStyles('shooting-star', `top:${r(80)}%,left:${r(20)}%,transform:rotate(-${r(180)}deg)`);

setStyles('shooting-star-right', `top:${r(80)}%,right:${r(20)},transform:rotate(${r(220)}deg)`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is lesser code:

```
 star.style.top = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1) +"%";
 star.style.left = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1) +"%;
```

etc.

Also, since you already use transform, you might as well use it for positioning. It works much better than setting `left` and `top` when used for animation.

```
let leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1
let topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1
star.style.transform = 'translate('+ leftPos +'px, '+topPos +'px) rotate(' + '-' + trans + ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you guys are interested, I ended up taking both your comments and finding a solution. I think this looks pretty good.

I really appreciate the assistance

```
const randomNum = (low, high) => {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
  return r;
};
const shootingStars = (name) => {
  const stars = document.querySelectorAll(name);
  const starsArray = [...stars];
  setInterval(() => {
    starsArray.forEach(el => {
      el.style.cssText = 'transform: rotate(' + randomNum(0, 180) + 'deg' + ') translateY(' + randomNum(0, 200) + 'px' + ')';
      });
    }, 9000);
  };
  shootingStars('.shooting-star');
  shootingStars('.shooting-star-right');
```